# How to edit files on my iPad's "On My iPad" folder using Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipad, icloud, file-transfer

I make Minecraft mods for the pocket edition of the game on my iPad, and as anyone would, they would want to be more time-efficient, with less testing and more time to code. I use Documents by Readdle for iCloud, but even then I have to wait a few seconds to send it to com.mojang>development_(whatever)_packs. I would like to know if there is a way to just edit the files directly in the On My iPad folder. Of course, my iPad is plugged in at all times.

[image: Only photos of my dog.]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Visual studio code only works on browser (not native iPadOS) I think, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Only works on browser? I'm not sure what you mean there.

Comment: Oh. I thought you were trying to run vscode on your iPad to edit local files

Comment: So really you are trying to access the On My iPad folder from your PC.

Comment: It's likely you can't do this since the file system is probably locked down access wise across a wired connection to your PC. I only found ways via iTunes to browse a file system on an iOS device on a pc

Comment: Hm. Looks like I'll have to do it the hard way. No worries, it still works I guess.